# How to do real-time audio convolution in Swift for iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

I am trying to build an iOS app where I have one mono-channel input (real-time from mic) and double-channel impulse response which needs to be real-time convolved with mono channel input and impulse response and will provide an output which is double-channel output (stereo). Is there a way to do that on iOS with Apple's Audio Toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

You should first decide whether you will be doing convolution in the time or frequency domain - there are benefits to both depending on the length of your signal/impulse response. This is somewhere you should do your own research.

For time domain, rolling your own convolution should be straightforward enough. For frequency domain you will be needing a FFT function, you could roll your own but more efficient versions will exist. For example the Accelerate framework has this implemented already.

But for basic I/O Audio Toolbox is a valid choice ..

Comment: I guess, it's well known that frequency domain convolution is faster. I am aware of vDSP (part of Accelerate framework) having 1-D convolution function; but does it do real-time operation? Is there any basic implementation of it? Does it use overlap-add or save?

Comment: It is true that frequency domain is normally faster , time domain can actually be faster for short filters/inputs. The overlapping method is not something that will come with an fft as it is normally pretty algorithm and implementation specific, and not truly part of the concept of an fft. And real time is something you should research.

Comment: To my extent of knowledge, overlap-add is done to consider for extra length obtained in time domain. It's true in time domain too.

Comment: Yep exactly, it is algorithm/implementation specific.

Comment: My question is more on if there is availability of such real-time implementation (regardless of the algorithm)